# Transform scala inner map

Tags: scala

hey i have Map like this:

```
val valueParameters = Map("key1"->"value","anotherkey1"->"value","thirdkey1"->"value","key2"->"value","anotherkey2"->"value","thirdkey2"->"value")
```

and pattern:

```
val pattern = """(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d{1,2}""".r

val result =  valueParameters.groupBy(x=>pattern.findAllIn(x._1).next().toInt).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).toMap
```

which gives: `Map[Int,Map[String,String]` and i want to remove the number from the first string of the second map which i dont need anymore so i can :  result(1)("key") not  result(1)("key1")

Comment: It seems not to be efficient, but you could do something like `result.mapValues{case (key, value) => ('removenumberfromkeyhere', value)}`

Comment: Be careful with mapValues. It is a lazy operation, so this might not be what you want because then every access will do the computation. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
val result1 = result.map { case (k,v) => 
  k -> v.map { case (a,b) => 
    val a1 = a.takeWhile(! _.isDigit)
    a1 -> b
  } 
}
```

Note that while using mapValues would result in shorter code, mapValues is a lazy operation that will do the computation every time you access the map, whereas mapping the entries will result in the computation being done once, which is usually what you expect in scala.

Comment: yes thanks that worked fine and yes i had to a.replaceAll("\\d","") because  will have two digit entries.

Comment: I modified the code to remove digits. But replaceAll obviously works just as well.